# Does Bazel need external-repo BUILD files to be in $WORKSPACE_ROOT/external?

Tags: bazel

I made a repository for glfw with this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")

new_git_repository(
  name = "glfw",
  build_file = "BUILD.glfw",
  remote = "https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git",
  tag = "3.2.1",
)
```

I put `BUILD.glfw` in the WORKSPACE root. When I built, I saw:

```
no such package '@glfw//': Not a regular file: [snipped/external/BUILD.glfw
```

I moved `BUILD.glfw` to `external/BUILD.glfw` and it seems to work, but I couldn't find documentation about this. The docs about `new_git_repository` say that `build_file` "...is a label relative to the main workspace."; I don't see anything about 'external' there.

Comment: What happens if you use the native `new_git_repository`, by removing the load statement? This may be a semantic difference between the Skylark and native versions of the rule.

Comment: Looks like this fixes it. Will open an issue.

Comment: Cool! I just posted an answer so we can resolve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to an inconsistent semantical difference between the native and (newer) Skylark versions of `new_git_repository`. To use the native `new_git_repository`, comment/remove the load statement:

```
# load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")
```

Comment: Accepted since this fixes it, but it's important to note that the native new_git_repository is deprecated and the docs point at the one in git.bzl

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5890

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that new_git_repository has the same problem that http_archive has, per Bazel issue [6225](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6225) you need to refer to the BUILD file for glfw as @//:BUILD.glfw